Why isnt the graph redrawn
Im making an app, where users can collide blocks, and they get graphs of the initial variable against the final velocity, i want the user to be able to switch which graph they want by clicking on different labels.
def Func__DoubleResults__():
  global _Type1,_Type2,_Type3,_Type4

  try:
    Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.destroy()
    Win__FinalValuesWindow__.destroy()
  except:
    pass

  draw_blocks(t=1, side1=float(mass1Entry.get()), side2=float(mass2Entry.get()))
  draw_blocks(t=2, side3=float(mass3Entry.get()), side4=float(mass4Entry.get()))

  _ScreenWidth = main_gui.winfo_screenwidth()
  _ScreenHeight = main_gui.winfo_screenheight()

  _WindowWidth = main_gui.winfo_width()
  _WindowHeight = main_gui.winfo_height()

  _NewX = 0
  _NewY = 0

  _GraphsWindowX = _NewX + main_gui.winfo_width() + 10

  Var_GraphsWindowWidth = main_gui.winfo_width() / 2
  Var_GraphsWindowHeight = main_gui.winfo_height() 

  main_gui.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(_WindowWidth, _WindowHeight, _NewX, _NewY))

  _TitleBarHeight = main_gui.winfo_rooty()-main_gui.winfo_y()
  
  Win__FinalValuesWindow__ = Tk()
  Win__FinalValuesWindow__.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(round(_WindowWidth +10), _ScreenHeight - _WindowHeight - 40 -50 - _TitleBarHeight , _NewX, _NewY + _WindowHeight+_TitleBarHeight))
  Win__FinalValuesWindow__.title("Final Values")
  Win__FinalValuesWindow__.configure(bg=bg_color)

  
  Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__ = Tk()
  Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(round(Var_GraphsWindowWidth),Var_GraphsWindowHeight+ _ScreenHeight - _WindowHeight - 40 -50 - _TitleBarHeight,_GraphsWindowX,_NewY))
  Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.title("Graphs")
  Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.configure(bg=bg_color)

  global Var_Axs1,Var_Axs2,Var_Fig1,Var_Fig2,Wgt__GraphsFor1And2,Wgt__GraphsFor3And4

  Var_Fig1,Var_Axs1 = plt.subplots(1,2)
  Var_Fig1.set_figheight(2.48)
  Var_Fig1.set_figwidth(5.5)

  Var_Fig2,Var_Axs2 = plt.subplots(1,2)
  Var_Fig2.set_figheight(2.48)
  Var_Fig2.set_figwidth(5.5)

  n = Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.winfo_height()

  print("Adadadadad",Var_GraphsWindowHeight+ _ScreenHeight - _WindowHeight - 40 -50 - _TitleBarHeight)

  Wgt__GraphsFor1And2 = Frame(master = Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__,width=round(Var_GraphsWindowWidth) - 20,height=round(Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.winfo_height()/4),bg=bg_color)
  Wgt__GraphsFor1And2.pack(side="top")

  Wgt__GraphsFor3And4 = Frame(master=Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__,width=round(Var_GraphsWindowWidth) - 20,height=round(Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__.winfo_height()/4),bg=bg_color)
  Wgt__GraphsFor3And4.pack(side="bottom")

  Wgt__Graphs1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(Var_Fig1,master = Wgt__GraphsFor1And2)
  Wgt_Graphs2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(Var_Fig2,master=Wgt__GraphsFor3And4)

  Var_Fig1.tight_layout()
  Var_Fig2.tight_layout()

  Wgt__Graphs1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
  Wgt_Graphs2.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)

  def Func__PlotGraph1__(type = 0):
    print(type)

    for ax in Var_Axs1:
      ax.cla()

    Var_YList = []
    Var_XList = [i/100 for i in range(0,101)] if type == "COR" else (list(range(0,101)) if type == "INITIAL" else list(range(1,101)))

    m1 = float(mass1Entry.get())
    m2 = float(mass2Entry.get())
    e = float(cOREntry.get())
    v1 = float(initial1Entry.get())
    v2 = -1 * float(initial2Entry.get())    
    
    if type ==  "INITIAL":
      for n in Var_XList:
        Var_YList.append((((m1 * n) + (m2 * v2) + (m2 * e * (v2 - n))) / (m1 + m2)))
      
    elif type == "MASS":
      for n in Var_XList:
        Var_YList.append(((n * v1) + (m2 * v2) + (m2 * e * (v2 - v1))) / (n + m2))
    else:
      for i in Var_XList:
        Var_YList.append(round((((m1 * v1) + (m2 * v2) + (m2 * i * (v2 - v1))) / (m1 + m2)),2))

    print(Var_XList,Var_YList)
    Var_Axs1[0].plot(Var_XList,Var_YList)
    Var_Axs1[0].set_xlabel(type,fontsize=6)
    Var_Axs1[0].set_title(type,fontsize=6)

  def Func__ChangeType__(event):
    name = event.widget
    name = list(Local_Vars.keys())[list(Local_Vars.values()).index(name)]

    _TypesDict = {
      "Wgt__Initial1Choice" : "INITIAL",
      "Wgt__Initial2Choice" : "INITIAL",
      "Wgt__Initial3Choice" : "INITIAL",
      "Wgt__Initial4Choice" : "INITIAL",
      "Wgt__Mass1Choice" : "MASS",
      "Wgt__Mass2Choice" : "MASS",
      "Wgt__Mass3Choice" : "MASS",
      "Wgt__Mass4Choice" : "MASS",
      "Wgt__Restitution1Choice" : "COR",
      "Wgt__Restitution2Choice" : "COR",
      "Wgt__Restitution3Choice" : "COR",
      "Wgt__Restitution4Choice" : "COR",
    }

    _TypeReferenece = {
      "Wgt__Initial1Choice" : _Type1,
      "Wgt__Initial2Choice" : _Type2,
      "Wgt__Initial3Choice" : _Type3,
      "Wgt__Initial4Choice" : _Type4,
      "Wgt__Mass1Choice" : _Type1,
      "Wgt__Mass2Choice" : _Type2,
      "Wgt__Mass3Choice" : _Type3,
      "Wgt__Mass4Choice" : _Type4,
      "Wgt__Restitution1Choice" : _Type1,
      "Wgt__Restitution2Choice" : _Type2,
      "Wgt__Restitution3Choice" : _Type3,
      "Wgt__Restitution4Choice" : _Type4,
    }

    _TypeReferenece[name] = _TypesDict[name]
    
    print(_TypeReferenece[name],_TypesDict[name])

    Func__PlotGraph1__(type=_TypesDict[name])
  


  Wgt__Block1Choices = Frame(Win__DoubleGraphsWindow__,bg=bg_color,height=170,width=273, padx=20, pady=20)
  Wgt__Initial1Choice = Label(master=Wgt__Block1Choices,text="As Initial Velocity Changes",bg=bg_color,highlightthickness=0)
  Wgt__Mass1Choice = Label(master=Wgt__Block1Choices,text="As Mass Changes",bg=bg_color,highlightthickness=0)
  Wgt__Restitution1Choice = Label(master=Wgt__Block1Choices,text="As Restitution Changes",bg=bg_color,highlightthickness=0)

  Wgt__Initial1Choice.bind("<Button-1>",lambda x: (Func__ChangeType__(event=x)))
  Wgt__Mass1Choice.bind("<Button-1>",lambda x:(Func__ChangeType__(event=x)))
  Wgt__Restitution1Choice.bind("<Button-1>",lambda x:(Func__ChangeType__(event=x)))

  global Var_Block1List,Wgt__Entry1,Wgt__Entry2,Wgt__Entry3,Wgt__Entry4,Wgt__FinalOut1,Wgt__FinalOut2,Wgt__FinalOut3,Wgt__FinalOut4
  Var_Block1List = [Wgt__Initial1Choice,Wgt__Mass1Choice,Wgt__Restitution1Choice]

  global Wgt__Entry1,Wgt__Entry2,Wgt__Entry3,Wgt__Entry4,Wgt__FinalOut1,Wgt__FinalOut2,Wgt__FinalOut3,Wgt__FinalOut4

  Wgt__Entry1 = Entry(master=Wgt__Block1Choices)
  Wgt__Entry1.insert(0,"Initial Value . . .")
  Wgt__Entry1.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda x:Wgt__Entry1.delete(0,END) if Wgt__Entry1.get() == "Initial Value . . ." else Wgt__Entry1.get())
  Wgt__Entry1.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda x:Wgt__Entry1.insert(0,"Initial Value . . .") if Wgt__Entry1.get() == "" else Wgt__Entry1.get())
  Wgt__Entry1.bind("<Return>",lambda x :Func__Output1__(event=x))

  Wgt__FinalOut1 = Entry(master=Wgt__Block1Choices)
  Wgt__FinalOut1.insert(0,"Final Value . . .")
  Wgt__FinalOut1.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda x:Wgt__FinalOut1.delete(0,END) if Wgt__FinalOut1.get() == "Final Value . . ." else Wgt__FinalOut1.get())
  Wgt__FinalOut1.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda x:Wgt__FinalOut1.insert(0,"Final Value . . .") if Wgt__FinalOut1.get() == "" else Wgt__FinalOut1.get())

  Wgt__Initial1Choice.pack(side="top",anchor="w")
  Wgt__Mass1Choice.pack(side="top" ,anchor="w")
  Wgt__Restitution1Choice.pack(side="top",anchor="w")
  Wgt__Entry1.pack(side="top",anchor="center",pady=(3,0))
  Wgt__FinalOut1.pack(side="top",anchor="center")


  Wgt__Block1Choices.place(x=0,y=239)

I tried to do just the clear method,and that didnt do anything, meaning that the plot was not being cleared, i looked online for answers and couldnt find anything.This is part of the function that makes the new windows, that contain the graphs
